# What Bug is this? Is it a Flea / Bedbug / Chigger / Mite?

Tags: bugs, bug-identification, dangerous-insects

I see these very tiny bugs on my walls at home. They are so small that it is very hard to notice unless you are extremely close to the wall and focus at a point. I was able to take a few photos.

These are some close-up photos:

[image]
[image]

This is how small they look from half a foot distance where it's hardly noticeable:

[image]

This is the stain I saw when I squashed them:

[image]

Some other things I noticed:

1. The photos I have shown are the biggest size I have seen so far so I am guessing these are the adult ones. All other ones are even smaller than this where they look like tiny speak of dust.
2. The extremely small ones jump when I try to squash them, where as the bigger ones like the photos above do not jump. They just crawl.
3. I do not have pets at home, but I have had guests who stayed at home who has cats at their home.
4. When I sleep at night and wake up, I see bits all over my back that looks like hives and I suspect if this insect might be causing it.
5. I only found this inside my home (apartment) walls.

Does anyone has any idea what this might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the site.

I think, but am not sure that these are bedbug nymphs. Based on the photo I found (below) from University of California Agriculture and Natural Resources, I think that you have the second stage nymph (left hand side, about 1/2 way down), which has an obvious gut filled with blood.

The best way to be sure is to get an expert in. Contact a local pest elimination company.

[image: nymphs]

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me @bob1 I appreciate that. Another point I did not mention before was, I noticed I have been getting hives on my back when I slept on the bed in those 2 particular rooms where I found them, but I don't have this issue when I sleep on the 3rd bedroom which is on the opposite end of the apartment. I heard only bedbugs and fleas might cause hives. I have a 8 yrs old and a 2 yr olds at home and I am concerned about them since one of these rooms is a kids bedroom and I have asked them not to use these beds for a few weeks until we find a solution.

Comment: Couple of questions if you don't mind: 1) Sometimes I see these bugs on other walls as well, such as bathroom walls or walls in the lounge rooms around frames, so do bed bugs are visible in other places as well during day time? 2) How can I get rid of them myself? Will anti cockroach spray like Mortein sprays kill them?

Comment: I recently called in my local pest control and they sprayed a crap load of chemicals all around the room, mattresses and the bed, but there are still some. So it appears it may need to done a few more times. But I am concerned about that because the chemicals are too strong and since I have kids at home, is there is a way I can manage to control these myself over a period of time?

Comment: @Neel No, you can't. Bedbugs became immune to many chemicals that used to kill them before. You can be lucky, but don't count on it. If the professionally applied spray was not enough, it will have to be repeated. It is unlucky that a basic pyrethroid-based spray from the chemist's would act better. Also, just cleaning does not help either. They can live in the cleanliest rooms and apartments. They can survive many months without blood and one single female that survived can start a new population.

Comment: Thank you @VladimirF for your input. These little buggers sounds more tougher than other insects like mosquitos. I am very worried on how am I gonna get rid of them from my place and how long it would take. Sounds like a huge challenge in front of me. Unfortunately this is my owned apartment so moving is not an option and all furnitures are brand new so getting rid of them is not feasible either.  Some say lavender, eucalyptus, lime, neem leaf, etc might repel them, but I dont know how effective they will be if bedbugs are already immune to many chemicals.

Comment: One way to kill them is to freeze them. So if you can find a freezer big enough.... A freezing warehouse would work if they take your things. At the same time as the spray kills those left in the house.

Comment: Bed bugs can be very tough to get rid of. You will most probably need a professional exterminator as most of them have become immune to over the counter poisons.

Comment: Here's a few things that could help:
Cold is not a good treatment. It would have to be REALLY cold for a long time. 
However they are very sensitive to HEAT. 140F for a 2-3 hours will kill them. You could rent a powerful heater and do one room at a time. Don't skip any rooms as you may miss some. 
You can also spray isopropyl alcohol directly onto them. This kills them and their eggs, but only the ones you see and spray. Once the alcohol dries, it won't effect any that come later.